# Cant understand why table is with double border.

Tags: html, css, joomla

I have a page: http://f1u.org/competitions

There are 3 tables. I can't understand why they all are with double border.

Please help me to understand.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Add this to the table's style:

```
border-collapse: collapse;
```

Answer (score 9):

By default, specifying `border="1"` on the `<table>` gives not only the table itself a border, but also all the `<td>`'s within it. There is also some default border spacing.

Adding [border-collapse](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/border-collapse) to the `<table>` and setting it to "collapse" will remove the spacing and collapse them into one border.

```
<table style="border-collapse: collapse;">
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add `border-collapse: collapse;` to the table styles

Answer (score -1):

Try to set `cellpadding` and `cellspacing` to 0.

Answer (score -3):

Ever heard of `border-collapse`?

Comment: Good point, but demeaning tone.